# DryIoc : Can't figure out how to register IDisposable Decorator object

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I'm trying to setup a decorator around an `IDisposable` db context:

```
c.Register<IContext, DbContext>(setup: Setup.With(trackDisposableTransient: true));

// c.Register<IContext, ConsoleTimedContext>(setup: Setup.Decorator);
```

If i uncomment the last line, the program throws:

`DryIoc.ContainerException: Registered Disposable Transient service Lib.DI.IContext with key {no key} and factory container won't be disposed by container. DryIoc does not hold reference to resolved transients, and therefore does not control their dispose. To silence this exception Register<YourService>(setup: Setup.With(allowDisposableTransient: true))  or set the rule Container(rules => rules.WithoutThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient()). To enable tracking use Register<YourService>(setup: Setup.With(trackDisposableTransient: true))  or set the rule Container(rules => rules.WithTrackingDisposableTransient())
   à DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3)
   à DryIoc.Container.ThrowIfInvalidRegistration(Factory factory, Type serviceType, Object serviceKey, Boolean isStaticallyChecked)
   à DryIoc.Container.Register(Factory factory, Type serviceType, Object serviceKey, IfAlreadyRegistered ifAlreadyRegistered, Boolean isStaticallyChecked)
   à DryIoc.Registrator.Register[TService,TImplementation](IRegistrator registrator, IReuse reuse, Made made, Setup setup, IfAlreadyRegistered ifAlreadyRegistered, Object serviceKey)`

How to mix `Setup.Decorator` with `trackDisposableTransient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is not available per Decorator registration (as of latest DryIoc v2.8.3).

For now you need to specify non transient reuse for decorator.

Feel free to raise an issue at: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc

Comment: I'm an absolute beginner in DryIoc, so do you mind explaining how?
And what's the side effect, if any?

Comment: The feature for transients tracking is a bit controversal and firstly was introduced to conform with new .NET Core MS.DI. So I made it as limited as possible, to see how it goes. It is not problem to add this to decotators (hopefully). But first the question: are your decorated services reused?

Comment: I'm not sure what _reused_ mean in DI context, but it's used everytime i make a query to my db.

Comment: I mean does the decorated services registered with `Reuse.Singleton` or other reuse, or no reuse specified at all?

Comment: No reuse specified at all. (have to ramp up my knowledge...)

Comment: Here is explanation: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ReuseAndScopes